# Error adding new member to linked positional list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I'm new to programming with Java and implementing algorithms.
I am trying to implement positional linked list in Java and I wrote the following methods and have trouble adding a new method to this list.
The add between method is for this purpose and does not work properly.
Can you tell me what is wrong with the addBetween method and how can I complete it?

```
import Position;
import EmptyListException;
import IllegalValueException;
import InvalidPositionException;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;


public final class LinkedPositionalList<E> implements PositionalList<E> {


private class Node implements Position {
    private E element;
    private Node next;
    private Node before;


    protected Node(E element, Node next, Node before) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.before = before;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public E getElement() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (next == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position no longer valid");
        return element;
    }

    public Node getBefore() {
        return before;
    }

    public void setBefore(Node before) {
        this.before = before;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public Object element() throws InvalidPositionException {
        return null;
    }
}

private int size = 0;
private Node header;
private Node trailer;

public LinkedPositionalList() {
    header = new Node(null, null, null);
    trailer = new Node(null, null, header);
    header.setNext(trailer);
}

private Node validate(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Node node = (Node) p;
    if (node.getNext() == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("p is no longer in the list");
    return node;
}

private Node position(Node node) {
    if (node == header || node == trailer)
        return null;
    return node;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (size == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    size = 0;
    header = null;
    trailer = null;
}

@Override
public boolean contains(E e) {
    Node temp = header;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (temp.element == e) {
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Position<E> first() throws EmptyListException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyListException("List is Empty");
    }
    System.out.println(header.element);
    return (Position<E>) header.element;
}

@Override
public Position<E> last() throws EmptyListException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyListException("List is Empty");
    }
    return (Position<E>) header.getBefore();
}

@Override
public boolean isFirst(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {

    if (header.getBefore() != null) {

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isLast(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    if (trailer.getNext() != null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public Position<E> before(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    return (Position<E>) node.getBefore();
}

@Override
public Position<E> after(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    return (Position<E>) node.getNext();
}

private Position<E> addBetween(E e, Node pred, Node succ) {
    Node newest = new Node(e, pred, succ);
    pred.setNext(newest);
    succ.setBefore(newest);
    size++;
    return (Position<E>) (newest);
}

@Override
public Position<E> insertFirst(E e) throws IllegalValueException {
    if (size > 0){
          insertBefore(header,e);
    }else {
        Node temp = new Node(e, header, null);
        header = temp;
        size++;
    }
    return (Position<E>) header;
    //        return addBetween(e, header, header.getNext());
}

@Override
public Position<E> insertLast(E e) throws IllegalValueException {

    Node temp = new Node(e, null, trailer);
    trailer = temp;
    size++;
    return (Position<E>) trailer;
    //        return addBetween(e, trailer.getBefore(), trailer);
}

@Override
public Position<E> insertBefore(Position<E> p, E e) throws InvalidPositionException, IllegalValueException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    return addBetween(e, node.getBefore(), node);
}

@Override
public Position<E> insertAfter(Position<E> p, E e) throws InvalidPositionException, IllegalValueException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    return addBetween(e, node, node.getNext());

}

@Override
public E remove(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    Node predecessor = node.getBefore();
    Node successor = node.getNext();
    predecessor.setNext(successor);
    successor.setBefore(predecessor);
    size--;
    E answer = node.getElement();
    node.setElement(null);
    node.setBefore(null);
    node.setNext(null);
    return answer;
}

@Override
public E replaceElement(Position<E> p, E e) throws InvalidPositionException, IllegalValueException {
    Node node = validate(p);
    node.setElement(e);
    return node.getElement();
}

@Override
public void swapElements(Position<E> p, Position<E> q) throws InvalidPositionException {

}

@Override
public Iterator<Position<E>> positionalIterator() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void sort(Comparator<E> comparator) {

}

@Override
public Position<E> find(E e) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Node i = header; counter < size; i = i.next) {
        if (e.equals(i)) {
            return (Position<E>) e;
        }
        counter++;

        return null;
    }return null;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Position<E>> findAll(E e) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    PositionalList.super.forEach(action);
}

@Override
public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return PositionalList.super.spliterator();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Didn't look at the whole code but the constructor of Node recieves elment, next and before. When you construct the new node in addBetween you send pred as next and succ as before, and I assume you meant to do it the opposite way.